# BreakIterator failing on Unicode UCD LineBreakTest

Tags: java, unicode, kotlin

The Unicode consortium provides a [LineBreakTest file](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/auxiliary/LineBreakTest.txt) for verifying that your line breaking code works properly. Using Unicode's *own library* `icu4j`, I cannot get the `× [0.3] HYPHEN-MINUS (HY) ÷ [999.0] NUMBER SIGN (AL) ÷ [0.3]` test case to pass. This ***works*** with java's built in library. Per the [ucd line break table](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/auxiliary/LineBreakTest.html), there should be a break there as well.

What am I missing here? Should there not be a break where it says? Is this locale dependent, but not specified in the LineBreakTest file?

Here is some kotlin code to reproduce.

```
val lineInstance = java.text.BreakIterator.getLineInstance()
val lineInstanceIcu4j = com.ibm.icu.text.BreakIterator.getLineInstance()

fun main() {
    println(lineBreakJava("-#"))
    println(lineBreakIcu4j("-#"))
}

fun lineBreakJava(text: String): MutableList<String> {
    lineInstance.setText(text)
    var start = lineInstance.first()
    var end = lineInstance.next()
    val breakableLocations = mutableListOf<String>()
    while (end != BreakIterator.DONE) {
        val substring = text.substring(start, end)
        breakableLocations.add(substring)
        start = end
        end = lineInstance.next()
    }
    return breakableLocations
}

fun lineBreakIcu4j(text: String): MutableList<String> {
    lineInstanceIcu4j.setText(text)
    var start = lineInstanceIcu4j.first()
    var end = lineInstanceIcu4j.next()
    val breakableLocations = mutableListOf<String>()
    while (end != BreakIterator.DONE) {
        val substring = text.substring(start, end)
        breakableLocations.add(substring)
        start = end
        end = lineInstanceIcu4j.next()
    }
    return breakableLocations
}
```

actual output:

```
[-, #]
[-#]
```

expected output:

```
[-, #]
[-, #]
```

edit:

Apparently IntelliJ had removed my icu4j dependency. After adding it back in I get the reverse of what was happening before. Now test cases that were passing are failing. I've updated the example with *one* of the failing cases.